# ethtool speed - Problems

Tags: connection

Today I got my 500 Mbits line, at the beginning ethtool was set to 100Mbits so I didn't get the full speed.

After I had unplugged and plugged in again, 1000 Mbits was displayed.

Just now the Internet was briefly interrupted (for whatever reason) and I found this setting back to 100Mbits.

How can I set that the speed is not always automatically adjusted here and remains at 1000 Mbits?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/log/syslog` the speed of your network connection is negotiated and any drop in speed should be reported. It sounds as though your cable is loose or faulty, is it cat6e or a good cat5e cable?  Try changing the cable and see if it is more stable

Comment: The cable is a cat5e, nothing strange with the wire, at the moment it works, i the logs i can only found that `May 14 09:04:55 XXX systemd-udevd[438]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.`, i can't disable autoneg with ethtool, after the command `sudo ethtool -s eno1 autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full` auto-negation is still enabled.

Comment: I haven't had an issue with auto negotiation, it usually works very well.  You said that the 500M connection is new, if the router is new too then maybe it has a faulty port, if it has more than one you could try plugging into another port.  I run at 1 gig over cat5e but my cables are < 5 meters and good quality.  It could still be your cable, if you have another it might we worth a try.  Hope you get it sorted

Comment: Until now i doesn't happen again, i need to check that the next days, the cable and router are not new, now i am on full-speed. Maybe the network-card is faulty? If it happends again in next time, is it worth to buy an extern card like that?:
https://tinyurl.com/networkCardAskUbuntu

If it happends again, maybe i can check it trought a script an force the setting?

Comment: Agree that cable or connections could be the problem. Removing and reinserting the cable like you did could dislodge some debris or dust, or just make a better connection. Bends in cables can affect the negotiation. 1G standards expect autonegotiation at both ends. Unless you have control over the speed/duplex settings at both ends it isn't advisable to manually set or disable autonegotiation. Cheaper to try another cable than to replace a NIC.